# wp_insert_posts for cpt with category or wp_set_post_categories

Tags: wordpress

I have an import-script for custom post-type contents. I need to add some categories to the posts. But after insert the categories are not added to the post (custom post type 'memember_pages')
My insert-statements:

```
$insertargs = array(
    'post_author'   => $user_id,
    'post_content'  => $page->beschreibung,
    'post_title'    =>  $page->name,
    'post_status'  =>  'publish',
    'post_category' =>  array(7,14),
    'post_type'     => 'member_pages'
);

$insertresult = wp_insert_post($insertargs,true);
```

`$insertresul`t returns the new post->ID, no errormessage.
The category-ID's exists of course.
The insert works, but without the categories.
The values 7,14 are only examples, which shows that I use (existing) ID's
I tried `wp_set_post_categories` too, but it also does not work.
`wp_set_post_categories` returns array(0) when using it.

Any idea to add categories to cpt?
thanks,
rudi

Comment: Was your `memember_pages` post type registered with `category` to use as it's taxonomy?

Comment: yes, I have registered it. On onother page I read that wp_set_post_categories only works with the post_type "post". 
So I use the function wp_set_object_terms(), and this function works successfull.
thanks a lot.